# how to find last modified of sharepoint document library?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to find last modified of document library.
how to find last modified of sharepoint document library using spservice or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSOM [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object exposes property [List.LastItemModifiedDate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.lastitemmodifieddate%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get the date and time that an item, field, or property of the list was last modified.

### Example

The following example demonstrates how to get and print the last modified date of a list via JSOM:

```
  var listTitle = 'Announcements';

  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
  context.load(list);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
        console.log(list.get_lastItemModifiedDate());
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
  );
```

Comment: How to do the same using Python 3.6?

Comment: @AakashBasu, here you go [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client)

Comment: I am totally new to REST APIs and am working on your magnificent work of art since last week. Posted my query here too: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/99. Couldn't find any example to do the same, hence asked here. Can you please help me in that?

Comment: I was waiting for your reply yesterday. Can you pls write a reply in this: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/99. Have an urgent requirement in doing this.